# Will deprecation of AsyncTask will affect the Room Database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room

I have one question that will deprecation of AsyncTask will affect the Room Database. What others should do who already have a huge app using room database, moreover delete and create operation is done by AsyncTask.

Comment: You should clarify in what language the codebase is in and/or explain why the existing notice in the documentation: [Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) isn't sufficient. Also realize that with R, AsyncTask will still be there for legacy support but the tools will want you to stop using them.

Comment: Why would you be using AsyncTask at all given [Room's wide support for async return types already](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-types)?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to run your app in api level 30+, Yes it affects. But you can update easily your code using Java.util.Concurrent Package.
For example
Create static instance of ExecutorService in your abstarct database class then use that instance to execute your query in background

```
public abstract class ExampleDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract ExampleDao exampleDao();

private static volatile WordDatabase INSTANCE;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS=4;
public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

public static ExampleDatabase getDatabase(final Context context){
    if(INSTANCE==null){
        synchronized (ExampleDatabase.class){
                INSTANCE= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WordDatabase.class,"word_database").build();

        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

}
public ExampleRepository{
 ....// 
 void insert(Example example){
  ExampleDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(()->{
            ExampleDao.insert(example);
            });
 }
}
```